# Why does my web application gets deployed two times in a row in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, jersey

i'm using NetBeans 7.3, Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Maven. When I deploy my application to Glassfish I get the following log:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 3ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 15ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 27ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 8ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 1ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
INFO: WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]
INFO: WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []
INFO: core.start_container_done
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
WARNING: DPL8027: Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/Tiago Peres/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playground-websockets/target/playground-websockets-1.0-SNAPSHOT/, as GlassFish counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
INFO: WELD-000900 1.1.8 (Final)
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
INFO: Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) para o contexto '/playground-websockets'
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a4ffb5b: startup date [Thu Mar 14 14:11:17 BRT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/beans.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'loginService': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.playground.core.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Tiago%20Peres/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playground-websockets/target/playground-websockets-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/playground-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/playground/core/service/impl/LoginServiceImpl.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.playground.core.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/beans.xml]]
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
INFO: Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'persistenceProvider' of type [class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'jpaDialect' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: persistence-websockets.xml should be located inside META-INF directory; cannot determine persistence unit root URL for class path resource [persistence-websockets.xml]
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'playground-websockets'
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: playground-websockets
    ...]
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: HHH000229: Running schema validator
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.gametitle
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, playedtimes, name, maximumnumberofplayers, rating, launchdate]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.player
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, nickname, facebookid]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.score
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, playedtimes, gametitle_id, victories, losses, player_id, points]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.hibernate_sequence
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [next_val]
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@56983a92: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,scoreRepositoryImpl,scoreRepository,gameTitleRepositoryImpl,gameTitleRepository,playerRepositoryImpl,playerRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,invitationRepositoryImpl,loggedPlayerRepository,queueRepositoryImpl,roomRepositoryImpl,invitationServiceImpl,loginService,queueServiceImpl,roomServiceImpl,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,persistenceProvider,jpaDialect,jpaVendorAdapter,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO: Using JTA UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl@45f8a36d
INFO: Using JTA TransactionManager: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper@46b16cfe
INFO: Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImpl@c91aca4
INFO: ***MyWebSocketApplication registered successfully in the Servlet***
INFO: ***LoginApplication registered successfully in the Servlet***
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [playground-websockets] at [/playground-websockets]
INFO: CORE10010: Loading application playground-websockets done in 21.807 ms
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (5) hora de inicialização : Felix (1.296ms), serviços de inicialização(23.324ms), total(24.620ms)
INFO: Created EjbThreadPoolExecutor with thread-core-pool-size 16 thread-max-pool-size 32 thread-keep-alive-seconds 60 thread-queue-capacity 2147483647 allow-core-thread-timeout false
```

Then it starts to do everything again for the "Jersey Application".

```
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: REST00001: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain
INFO: The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.
INFO: The Admin Console is starting. Please wait.
INFO: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Tiago-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Tiago-PC:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) para o contexto ''
WARNING: DPL8027: Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Users/Tiago Peres/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playground-websockets/target/playground-websockets-1.0-SNAPSHOT/, as GlassFish counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
INFO: CORE10010: Loading application __admingui done in 2.489 ms
INFO: The Admin Console application is loaded.
INFO: Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) para o contexto '/playground-websockets'
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2b58140c: startup date [Thu Mar 14 14:11:40 BRT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/beans.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'loginService': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.playground.core.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Tiago%20Peres/Documents/NetBeansProjects/playground-websockets/target/playground-websockets-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/playground-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/playground/core/service/impl/LoginServiceImpl.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.playground.core.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jndi:/server/playground-websockets/WEB-INF/beans.xml]]
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
INFO: Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'persistenceProvider' of type [class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Bean 'jpaDialect' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: persistence-websockets.xml should be located inside META-INF directory; cannot determine persistence unit root URL for class path resource [persistence-websockets.xml]
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'playground-websockets'
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: playground-websockets
    ...]
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: HHH000229: Running schema validator
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.gametitle
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, playedtimes, name, maximumnumberofplayers, rating, launchdate]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.player
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, nickname, facebookid]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.score
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, playedtimes, gametitle_id, victories, losses, player_id, points]
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: playground.hibernate_sequence
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [next_val]
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6bbeacbf: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,playerRepositoryImpl,playerRepository,gameTitleRepositoryImpl,gameTitleRepository,scoreRepositoryImpl,scoreRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,invitationRepositoryImpl,loggedPlayerRepository,queueRepositoryImpl,roomRepositoryImpl,invitationServiceImpl,loginService,queueServiceImpl,roomServiceImpl,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,persistenceProvider,jpaDialect,jpaVendorAdapter,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO: Using JTA UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl@32ada1c
INFO: Using JTA TransactionManager: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper@46b16cfe
INFO: Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImpl@c91aca4
INFO: ***MyWebSocketApplication registered successfully in the Servlet***
INFO: ***LoginApplication registered successfully in the Servlet***
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [playground-websockets] at [/playground-websockets]
INFO: playground-websockets foi implantado com sucesso em 19.620 milissegundos.
INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
```

I don't understand why the application has to be also deployed to Jersey. I don't have any Restfull service, why would I need it? Can I remove it? How?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: I'm getting the following runtime error and I think this double deploy may be what's causing it: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport$MethodCacheKey], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first extract from the log shows Glassfish starting up.  If the application was deployed previously, Glassfish loads it as it starts.

The second sequence is the deploy of the current version of your application from your IDE, driven by the Oracle Glassfish plugin, into Glassfish.  It doesn't track the state of which version of the web app was deployed across the Glassfish stop/start - so it just re-publishes it.

If Glassfish is aleady running when you publish an update, it should only publish once.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The solution I found yesterday for this was to always undeploy my application before stoppping glassfish, but I didn't know why it worked. When I arrive home I'm gonna try to execute my project without shutting down the server, it seems much easier than "execute, test, undeploy, stop, compile, execute, ...". If it works I'll mark the answer as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: When I try to republish my application I get an error from Spring Data JPA, but since I didn't get any of the problems I usually had when redeploying I'm marking this answer as correct.